# jquery syntax on passing variable to selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have a very basic question im trying to pass in a variable to the following selector

```
var image = $('#'+$ID ul li).find('input').eq(0).val();
```

but there is an syntax error what do I need to change?

Comment: `$('#'+$ID + ' ul li')` may be ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want this:

```
$('#' + $ID + ' ul li')...
```

You forgot to open the string again.

Just in case `$ID` happens to be a jQuery object:

```
$('#' + $ID.attr('id') + ' ul li')...
```

Comment: That does not quite work, maybe it's something i'm doing wrong can you look at this JsBin? http://jsbin.com/acaxos/1/edit

Comment: @Edward I don't know how to update jsbin, but you need `'Wednesday'` rather than `Wednesday` (quotes) and a space before `ul`, i.e. `' ul...`